# Map Entity to the correct subclass

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the following classes Entity, BaseClass, SubClass1, SubClass2.

```
public class Entity {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private String type;
  private String field3;
  private String field4;
}
```

```
public class BaseClass {
  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private String type;
}
```

```
public class SubClass1 extends Base {
  private String field3;
}
```

```
public class SubClass2 extends Base {
  private String field4;
}
```

Entity is obtained from by call an API. Depending on the value of the `type` property of the BaseClass, I want to map the Entity to the corresponding subclass.

One option I can think of mapping is below,

```
@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {
  SubClass1 mapEntityToSubClass1(Entity entity);
  
  SubClass2 mapEntityToSubClass2(Entity entity);

}
```

I will invoke either of the methods `mapEntityToSubClass1` or `mapEntityToSubClass2` conditionally based on the `type` in my business logic. Since I will be getting a List from the external API, looping through, checking the type in `Entity` doesn't seem good to me. In my business logic there are currently 4 subclasses and in future there can be more and the logic becomes more clumsy.

Is there a better way of implementing the same in mapstruct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but you just want to pick which subclass to map to based on a field in the source? Don't do that in the business logic, simply use a default method. Something like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface EntityMapper {
    default BaseClass map(Entity entity) {
        if(entity.getType().equals("a"))
            return mapEntityToSubClass1(entity);

        if(entity.getType().equals("b"))
            return mapEntityToSubClass2(entity);

        throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported base type");
    }

    Sub1 mapEntityToSubClass1(Entity entity);

    Sub2 mapEntityToSubClass2(Entity entity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shadov this helps. Implemented the same.